# MongoDB High number of connection spike from mongos to mongod

Tags: mongodb

We have a sharded MongoDB cluster. We are noticing connection spike in mongod from avg 2K connection to peak of 20K (and more) connections for every 5 mins. Connections that were opened during peak stays for 1 min and all of them get closed after 1 min. This connection spike pattern happens for every 5 mins.

We controlled the connection spike by tuning ShardingTaskExecutorPoolMaxSize and taskExecutorPoolSize on mongos, but the spike didn't go away fully.

We moved our product from one cloud provider to another cloud provider with the same application. No additional connections from application after we moved to new cloud provider. In the older cloud provider there is no connection spike pattern and the number of connection in mongod remain flat. However after moving to new cloud provider connection spike started happening.

Is there any parameter that needs to be set on mongod or mongos to control this connection spike pattern?

From connPoolStats older env has very less totalCreated connections, whereas in newer env, totalCreated connection is way high.
Older "totalCreated" : 346249 --> this is from one older env mongos, where mongos is running for many months.
Newer "totalCreated" : 2087203 --> this is from newer env mongos, here mongos is running for only few days.

MongoDB version is 3.6 Wiredtiger.

Any pointers will be really helpful.

Thanks,
~ila.

Comment: Well, you need to debug this, i.e. see what the connections are used for at least. If you don't know how to do that I suggest hiring a consultant.

Comment: 3.6 is about to get end of lifed too, you'd surely have easier time troubleshooting this on 4.4.